# stop child anchor tag from directing to other page

Tags: jquery

```
var saved_recipe = [];
var videoIndex = 0;
  function createVideoList() {
  var list = "";
  var v = 0;
  $.each(videoarr, function (index, value) {
    var name = videoarr[v].name;
    var img = videoarr[v].img;
    var date = videoarr[v].date;
    list = list + "<div id='video'><a id='saved_recipe'>Like this</a><img 
           src='" + img +  "' id='videoimg'/><h4>"
           + name + "</h4><p class='videodate'>" + date + "</p></div>"
    v = v + 1;
  });
  $('#videoresult').html(list);
 }

 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#videopage", function () {
  createVideoList();
  $('#videoresult div').on('tap', function (e) {
    videoIndex = $(this).index();
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#videodetailpage", { role: "page" });
  })
 })

$(document).on("tap", "#saved_recipe", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  saved_recipe.push(videoarr[videoIndex]);
  console.log(saved_recipe);
});
```

The effect I want is when I tapped on the saved button I just want to push the array value to the array. Now it's redirecting me to the other page.
I have a search on StackOverflow, all the answers said to use either e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation() or return false. But all don't work for me, it still redirecting to the other page. Do yall know why it did not work?

Comment: Maybe another event is fired along with the tab, like a click event or something. The link then still reacts to the click event even when the tab event is prevented.

Comment: what do you mean? is it both tap event clashing with each other?

Comment: What I mean is that 'tap' is a jQuery Mobile event for gestures on a touch screen. However a lot of devices also deliver a 'click' event when you tap a touch screen, which is a regualr jQuery event. You catch the tap event and prevent its default behaviour, but you do not catch the click event to prevent its default. The default of a click on a link of course is to open it. Try `on('tap click',...` it depends on your device and jQuery version, though, so all I can do is guess.